# Multiprocessing with large no of files

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to solve a problem. I would appreciate your valuable input on this.

Problem statement:
I am trying to read a lot of files (of the order of 10**6) in the same base directory. Each file has the name that matches the pattern (YYYY-mm-dd-hh), and the content of the files are as follows

```
mm1, vv1
mm2, vv2
mm3, vv3
.
.
.
```

where `mm` is the minute of the day and `vv`” is some numeric value with respect to that minute. I need to find, given a start-time (ex. 2010-09-22-00) and an end-time (ex. 2017-09-21-23), the average of all `vv`’s.

So basically user will provide me with a `start_date` and `end_date`, and I will have to get the average of all the files in between the given date range. So my function would be something like this:

```
get_average(start_time, end_time, file_root_directory):
```

Now, what I want to understand is how can I use multiprocessing to average out the smaller chunks, and then build upon that to get the final values.

NOTE: I am not looking for linear solution. Please advise me on how do I break the problem in smaller chunks and then sum it up to find the average.
I did tried using `multiprocessing` module in python by creating a pool of 4 processes, but I am not able to figure out how do I retain the values in memory and add the result together for all the chunks.

Comment: In addition to being  very broad, it's unclear exactly what you want to know. That said, one general (and very common) way to communicate between processes is by using  one or more `multiprocessing.Queue` objects.

Comment: Well I agree the statement is broad, and I also agree realistically no file system could handle 10^6 files in a single directory. That said my main goal here is to build a prototype

Answer (score 0):

You process is going to be I/O bound.
Multiprocessing may not be very useful, if not counterproductive.

Moreover your storage system, base on enormous number of small files, is not the best. You should look at a time serie database such as influxdb.

Comment: Agree the process is going to be i/o bound, but I am looking to solve the problem with files. Storing data in a db is not the option for me since data generation is not handled by me

Comment: Even you don't handle data generation, you can still process them to make them easier to query. It really depends on your query pattern : once or often, large amount of data or sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the actual processing is trivial—a sum and count of each file—using multiple processes or threads is not going to gain much.  This is because 90+% of the effort is opening each file and transferring into memory its content.

However, the most obvious partitioning would be based on some per-data-file scheme.  So if the search range is (your example) `2010-09-22-00` through `2017-09-21-23`, then there are seven years with (maybe?) one file per hour for a total of 61,368 files (including two leap days).

61 thousand processes do not run very effectively on one system—at least so far.  (Probably it will be a reasonable capability some years from now.)  But for a real (non-supercomputing) system, partitioning the problem into a few segments, perhaps twice or thrice the number of CPUs available to do the work.  This desktop computer has four cores, so I would first try 12 processes where each independently computes the sum and count (number of samples present, if variable) of 1/12 of the files.

Interprocess communication can be eliminated by using threads.  Or for process oriented approach, setting up a pipe to each process to receive the results is a straightforward affair.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand 61k process is not the right thing. I also have a 4 core more machine, and I am just trying to scale things so even 4 process at a time is good for me. Could you please provide some sample code and libraries to accomplish the task. Even if you could share some blog or online link that you have used in the past would be great thanks!